# Update status in a custom Kubernetes controller in golang

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, kubebuilder

I am building a Go Kubernetes operator. I have used kubebuilder to create it.
I want to store some internal details in the CRD status. I have tried :

- To update the whole resource :

```
if err = r.Client.Update(ctx, upCRD); err != nil {
    return ctrl.Result{}, client.IgnoreNotFound(err)
}
```

- And to update only the status :

```
if err = r.Status().Update(ctx, upCRD); err != nil {
    return reconcile.Result{}, client.IgnoreNotFound(err)
}
```

The status struct is defined as follows :

```
type HAAuditStatus struct {
    ChaosStrategyCron  cron.EntryID       `json:"chaosStrategyCron,omitempty"`
    TestStatus         TestStatus         `json:"testStatus,omitempty"`
    MetricStatus       MetricStatus       `json:"metricStatus,omitempty"`
    RoundRobinStrategy RoundRobinStrategy `json:"roundRobinStrategy,omitempty"`
    FixedStrategy      FixedStrategy      `json:"fixedStrategy,omitempty"`
    NextChaosDateTime  int64              `json:"nextChaosDateTime,omitempty"`
    Created            bool               `json:"created,default=false"`
}
```

No error is raised and the specs fields modified are actually persisted but not the status field whose values remain the default at the next reconciling step.
I have looked at the other issues on GitHub or StackOverflow but any suggestion made solved my issue and I can't figure out what is the problem. For a a bigger picture, you can refer to the [repo](https://github.com/PaulBarrie/ha-audit-operator) where the operator is located.

Any suggestion is very welcomed :)

Comment: Doesn't `status` have to be explicitly declared as a subresource? I haven't worked with kubebuilder before; there is some documentation [here](https://book-v1.book.kubebuilder.io/basics/status_subresource.html) that looks like it might be relevant.

Comment: Indeed but its is set by default when the api is generated. So the annotation `// +kubebuilder:subresource:status` is already in the types file. I will update the issue with the Github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have found the reason why the status were not updated.

Before updating the status, I was also updating the spec fields (to give some feedback to the user on created resources).

The issue is caused by the fact that the specs updates trigger a new reconcilation, and the instruction after this update (among them the status update) were not execute.

I realized that using specs to give feedback to the user is not suitable and the events were more appropriate for this purpose.